# Writing into file with vb.net when the session starts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to write into file with vb.net in the Global.asax file 
Please someone give me example how to write that kind of file in the Global.asax

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to edit a file when your application starts?

Comment: When the session is start i want to write that into a file(in vb.net) in the Glabal.asax can you show me example please how you do it? :)

Comment: Sounds like a BAD idea to write directly to a configuration file - unless you are a hacker and trying to break things on purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your Global.asax file:

```
 Protected Sub Session_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     Dim mydocpath As String = "c:\\path\\to\folder";

     Using outfile As New StreamWriter(mydocpath & "\MyTextFile.txt")
         outfile.Write("Some message")
     End Using 
 End Sub
```

You might want to look at a logging package like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), they are much more robust than this example.